# Create list box in runtime and change its color via menu in runtime

Tags: vb.net, listbox, runtime, basic

I need to write this small program in visual basic, but i face a problem which is i can't change the color or add list form text file during runtime.

this is picture of what i wont to do

http://i62.tinypic.com/30tghh0.png

And this is the code i wrote so far,,

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Dim listBox1 As New System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
        listBox1.Text = "New List"
        listBox1.Location = New Point(25, 25)
        listBox1.Size = New Size(380, 280)
        Me.Controls.Add(listBox1)
        OpenToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        SaveToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        SaveAsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        CloseToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        EditToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExirToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExirToolStripMenuItem.Click
        End

    End Sub


    Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click

        If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            Dim myfile As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            Dim allLines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(myfile)
            For Each line As String In allLines
                ListBox1.Items.Add(line)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem as you see is in OpenToolStripMenuItem sub with line `ListBox1.Items.Add(line)`

is there is no listbox1 because is not created yet.the same with color, save and the rest.

so, please help me to solve it.

Comment: Not sure why you have the code there but, if you click the `NewToolStripMenuItem`, the Listbox will be created. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the declaration of ListBox1 out to the Class level:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private ListBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

    Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
        ListBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
        ...
    End Sub

    ...

End Class
```

*But why create it at run-time like this?  You could add it at design-time and set the Visible() property to False.  When the New button is clicked, you change Visible() to True.  Unless you need a new ListBox to be created each time so you have more than one?  If so, how will they be laid out?...